# Extjs 4.2.1 Stacked bar chart Minimum and maximium values changes based on store

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

Hi i am working on a extjs 4.2.1 application in which i am using the bar chart (stacked) . In x axis i want range from -100(minimum) to maximum (100) with a difference of 20 (majorTickSteps=10).

Below is the code

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
fields: ['name', 'cost','sell'],
data: [
    {'name': "2013", 'cost': -36.483395098129556, 'sell': 25.516604901870444},
    {'name': "2013", 'cost': -27.483395098129556, 'sell': 8.516604901870444},
    {'name': "2013", 'cost': -35.483395098129556, 'sell': 19.516604901870444},
    {'name': "2013", 'cost': -25.483395098129556, 'sell': 33.516604901870444}
]
```

});

```
Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        id:'chart',
        width: 580,
        height: 165,
        animate: true,
        store: store,
        axes: [{
            type: 'Numeric',
            position: 'bottom',
            fields: ['cost','sell'],  
            grid: true, 
            minimum: -100,
            maximum:100      
        }, {
            type: 'Category',
            position: 'left',
            fields: ['name']
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'bar',
            axis: 'bottom',
             stacked: true,
            xField: 'name',
            yField: ['cost','sell']
        }]
    });
```

- if stacked = true , x axis minimum and maximum values are changed based on the store
- if stacked = false, x axis minimum and maximum remains same , but it is not stacked.

I need stacked bar chart with minimum and maximum values which i specified. How can i proceed . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?250004) (EXTJSIV-7844) in ExtJS.  A solution is to override the `processView` function for your axis.

The original code looks like this ([see the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Numeric.html#Ext-chart-axis-Numeric)):

```
processView: function() {
    var me = this,
        chart = me.chart,
        series = chart.series.items,
        i, l;

    for (i = 0, l = series.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (series[i].stacked) {
            // Do not constrain stacked charts (bar, column, or area).
            delete me.minimum;
            delete me.maximum;
            me.constrain = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (me.constrain) {
        me.doConstrain();
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is code in place to intentionally prevent you from doing what you're trying to do.  I'm not sure *why* the code is there, but a simple fix is to override the `processView` function such that it doesn't do that.

```
processView: function() {
    var me = this;

    if (me.constrain) {
        me.doConstrain();
    }
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7Rr4/) for a working example.